# BST node delete function failing at recursive call

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
void search(struct node **root, struct node **cursor,
            struct node **parent, int data, int *found) {
    struct node *iterator = *root;

    *cursor = NULL, *parent = NULL;
    *found = FALSE;

    while (iterator != NULL) {
        if (data == iterator->data) {
            *found = TRUE;
            *cursor = iterator;
            break;
        } else
        if (data <= iterator->data) {
            *parent = iterator;
            iterator = iterator->left;
        } else {
            *parent = iterator;
            iterator = iterator->right;
        }
    }
}

void delete(struct node **root, int data) {
    int found;
    struct node *cursor, *parent;

    if (*root == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR! Binary Search Tree Empty!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    search(root, &cursor, &parent, data, &found);
    if (found == FALSE) {
        printf("ERROR! Element not found in Binary Tree!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    //  If the Node has No Children
    if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right == NULL) {
        if (parent->left == cursor) {
            parent->left = NULL;
        } else {
            parent->right = NULL;
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right != NULL) {
        if (parent->left == cursor) {
            parent->left = cursor->right;
        } else {
            parent->right = cursor->right;
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    if (cursor->left != NULL && cursor->right == NULL) {
        if (parent->left == cursor) {
            parent->left = cursor->left;
        } else {
            parent->right = cursor->left;
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    // If node has two children
    if (cursor->left != NULL && cursor->right != NULL) {
        struct node *iterator = cursor;
        iterator = iterator->right;
        while (iterator->left != NULL) {
            iterator = iterator->left;
        }
        cursor->data = iterator->data;
        printf("\n%i\n", iterator->data);
        delete(&iterator, iterator->data);
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree Delete function. I have tested for many BSTs however it fails when I remove a node with two children. It fails at the **recursive** call. It gives a **Segmentation fault 11**. What should I do?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior for accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: How does the lifetime of the object end? 'iterator' is still there, how is it gone?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 2 The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
guaranteed to be reserved for it.[...] 34) If an object is referred to outside of its
lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime. 7.22.3 Memory management functions 1 [...] The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
until the deallocation.[...]*

Comment: Okay, so how can I fix this issue then?

Comment: Don't access an object after you `free()` it? That doesn't sound *too* complicated, does it?

Comment: I do not think I am accessing an object after freeing it, i am accessing it before freeing it.

Comment: I am sorry. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: You have: `if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right == NULL) {
        …; free(cursor);
    }
    if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right != NULL) { … } …`.  When you free the cursor, your code goes onto the next `if` block, accessing the freed cursor.  You either need a `return` or similar after the `free(cursor);` or you need to use `if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right == NULL) { …
        free(cursor);
    }
    else if (cursor->left == NULL && cursor->right != NULL) { … } …`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JonathanLeffler. I changed the remaining ifs to else ifs and added a return to the end of each if/else if code block but still same error. :(

Comment: It very often works out that where there's one problem, there are several others lurking.  I'm seeing problems when trying to delete the root node of the tree when the tree is non-empty.  The code ends up dereferencing `parent->left` when `parent` is a null pointer.  That leads to a crash.  Your analysis in `delete()` doesn't seem to account for a null parent.  Now, there's a chance that my insertion code is different from yours, but at the least, you need to work out what happens when the value in the root node is deleted. I'm not entirely clear why you have the recursive delete call.

Comment: I realised what my mistake was. I was assigning the value of iterator->data to cursor->data before recursively deleting iterator. it made different nodes in two different locations of the same value, hence violating the BST property. Thank you fo your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `delete` function is you do not return after each `free(cursor);`.  Instead you keep testing the next case, dereferencing `cursor` that was just freed.  The problem is primarily when `cursor` has 1 or no children.

Comment: Considering the function recurses *until* the `cursor` has less than two children, the undefined behavior is unavoidable.